# How to Center a Horizontal Menu Inside a box(div)

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at folloeing example and let me know how I can center the  inside the .menuBox div. As you can see I already used the margin: 0 auto; property inside the .menuBox div but I do not know why it is not working?!
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hBDv9/30/

Can you please let me know how I can force a ul and li elements to be auto centered in parent box?
Thanks for your time and comments

Answer (score 1):

The elements are floated to the left, that's why they are not centered.

Auto margin works fine (it centers the whole red div on the page).

The solution might be to have `margin: auto` instead of `float: left`

Comment: Thanks Peter I got it, But why there are some spaces between list items after changing to margin: auto; ? once again thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using display: inline-block on your LIs, and some text-align: center on your UL.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBDv9/33/